# How to group time series data by arbitrary dates in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data.frame like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
  DateTime = seq(ISOdate(2015, 1, 1, 0), by = 15 * 60, length.out = 35040),
  kWh = abs(rnorm(35040, mean = 550, sd = 50))
)
```

and a vector such as:

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2015-01-15", "2015-02-17", "2015-03-14", "2015-04-16", 
                   "2015-05-16", "2015-06-18", "2015-07-15", "2015-08-15",
                   "2015-09-16", "2015-10-13", "2015-11-17", "2015-12-17"))
```

What I want to do is add a column to `df` that indicates what accounting period each entry is attributed to.  For example every entry from the beginning of the data through the last entry on 2015-01-14 would be given a value of 201501 because they are attributed to the January 2015 accounting period.  Again, every value from from 2015-01-15 to the last value on 2015-02-16 would be given a value of 201502.

I was hoping that there would be a solution using `lubridate` as I'd rather not convert to an `xts` or `zoo` based object.  Performance is also somewhat important as I will have to do this for a couple hundred such data sets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer,  I didn't realize `cut` also works with `POSIXct` objects.

```
df$Period <- cut(df$DateTime, breaks = as.POSIXct(dates), 
                 labels = 201502:201512)
```

It's important to convert the `dates` into `POSIXct` object because otherwise `cut` throws an error saying that they breaks are not formatted correctly.